# How to override get_serializer_class in APIView to change the serializer_class attribute in a class based view according to a specific condition.?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-serializer

What I am trying to do is set the serializer_class attribute through get_serializer_class method like this

```
    if user.role==1 :
      return adminLoanView 
    elif user.role==2 :
      return agentLoanView 
    else:
      return customerLoanView
```

And in def put() function use these serializers based on the logged in user to perform different function that is admin and agent can only edit specific fields. And customer can not edit anything.
I am still a beginner in DRF so let me know if there is any other better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Django's own `User` model which has `.is_superuser` and `.is_staff` fields, you can override the the `get_serializer_class()` like so:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    user = self.request.user
    if user.is_superuser:
        return SerializerClassWithHigherPermissions
    elif user.is_staff:
        return SerializerClassWithIntermediatePermissions
    else:
        return SerializerClassWithCustomerPermissions
```

If you have a custom User model with a `OnetoOneField` on the `User` model, you could access that instance through the `user` instance in the view, and then check for permissions conditions.